# Strange behavior with ctrl + shift + e shortcut

Tags: release-juno

When I press `ctrl + shift + e` something strange happens and I can't write nothing anymore for a few keystrokes.

[image]

In the gif above I press `ctrl + shift + e` multiple times. You can see that the first letter is lower case and after upper case. Some strokes later everything is removed. After I try to remove the `e` with `ctrl + z` and the same thing happens.

This problem affects all apps that I tried (scratch, vscode, chrome, terminal etc).

I've looked in settings to see if is a shortcut for something, but didn't find id. I'm using juno beta release.

Comment: I think it's a ubuntu problem. I'm using KDE neon now and it has the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

I guess I found solution:

`export GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple"`

and then run vscode (or another app) from the same shell.
If that doesnt work try this:
`export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"`

As for me second variant works well.

To save this for all application put line into /etc/environment, or per-user in ~/.gnomerc.
(The export command doesn't go in those files, just a new line with `GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"` or `GTK_IM_MODULE="gtk-im-context-simple"`.)

Original: https://superuser.com/a/1334194

Comment: ` export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"`  did the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: update: that solved the vscode problem, but created another one. I can't use accents anymore (my language is portuguese and we use accents).